# Simplifying trig expression

Tags: trigonometry

I was working through some trig exercises when I stumbled upon the following problem:

Prove that: $ \cos(A+B) \cdot \cos(A-B)=\cos^2A- \sin^2B$.

I started out by expanding it such that 
$$ \cos(A+B) \cdot \cos(A-B)=(\cos A \cos B-\sin A \sin B) \cdot (\cos A \cos B+ \sin A \sin B),$$
which simplifies to: 
$$ \cos^2 A \cos^2 B- \sin^2 A \sin^2 B .$$ 
However, I don't know how to proceed from here. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track! From where you left off:

$\cos^2A\cos^2B-\sin^2A\sin^2B = \cos^2A(1-\sin^2B)-\sin^2A\sin^2B$
$ = \cos^2A - \sin^2B(\cos^2A+\sin^2A)=\cos^2A-\sin^2B$

**Note**: using *\sin* and *\cos* results in prettier TeX formatting.

Comment: How did you get from $\cos^2 A \cos^2 B=\cos^2 A (1-\sin^2 B)$?

Comment: From $\sin^2B + \cos^2B = 1$.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are most welcome Emile. :)

Answer (score 2):

The identities

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{e^{i \theta}+e^{- i \theta}}{2}$$
$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{e^{i \theta}-e^{- i \theta}}{2i}$$

can reduce a trigonometric identity to a identity of polynomials. Let's see how this works in your example:

$$\cos(A+B) \cos(A-B)=\cos(A)^2-\sin(B)^2$$

is rewritten into:

$$\frac{e^{i (A+B)}+e^{- i (A+B)}}{2} \frac{e^{i (A-B)}+e^{- i (A-B)}}{2}=\left(\frac{e^{i A}+e^{- i A}}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{e^{i B}-e^{- i B}}{2i}\right)^2$$

now we change it into a rational function of $X = e^{i A}$ and $Y = e^{i B}$:

$$\frac{(X Y + \frac{1}{X Y})(\frac{X}{Y} + \frac{Y}{X})}{4} = \frac{(X + \frac{1}{X})^2 + (Y - \frac{1}{Y})^2}{4}$$

and you can simply multiply out both sides to see that they are both $\frac{1}{4}\left(X^2 + \frac{1}{X^2} + Y^2 + \frac{1}{Y^2}\right)$ which proves the trigonometric equality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed answer.
**Let's rock!**
$$
\require{cancel}\begin{align}
\cos\left(A-B\right)\cdot\cos\left(A+B\right)&=\left(\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B\right)\left(\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B\right)\\
&=\cos^2A\cos^2B-\sin^2A\sin^2B\\
&=\cos^2A\left(1-\sin^2B\right)-\sin^2A\sin^2B\\
&=\cos^2A-\sin^2B\cos^2A-\sin^2A\sin^2B\\
&=\cos^2A-\sin^2B\cancelto{1}{\left(\cos^2A+\sin^2A\right)}\\
&=\cos^2A-\sin^2B
\end{align}
$$
I hope this helps.